# Why can't I create Sublime's "subl" soft-link?

Tags: terminal, sublimetext

I'm trying to make terminal work with `subl` but it's not working.

The instruction say to input this:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

The response I get is:

```
ln: /Users/marlon/bin/subl: File exists
```

Which seems to be good. Then it says to input:

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

which also works but, then when I type:

```
subl ~/.gemrc
```

I get: `-bash: subl: command not found`.

Also for later in the tutorial I have to put:

```
subl README.md
```

and I get the same error message.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

This is what I get when I type `env $PATH`:

```
env: /Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/marlon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/Users/marlon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/marlon/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `~/bin` directory in your PATH?

To test this, type:

```
env $PATH
```

You should see `~/bin` or `/Users/marlon/bin` somewhere in there.

Also, try typing `which subl`. It should say `/Users/marlon/bin/subl`.

To fix this, edit your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file and add:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

at the end. If you have RVM or rbedit, put the line just above their initializers.

See "[What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)" for loads of information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't quite understand how to fix it however. When I type which subl I don't get any response but env $PATH does what you said. How do I edit "~/.bash_profile" and add "export PATH=~/bin:$PATH"? Sorry, I'm just trying to figure out the terminal.

Comment: Before doing anything else, try `rehash subl`, which tells the OS to look up and remember the `subl` command. That *might* be all you need. Otherwise, you're on Mac OS, so use `pico ~/.bash_profile` from the command-line. Once that's done you should be able to use `subl`. If not, you'll need to edit your question and add the output of `env $PATH` to your question so we can see how it's formatted.

Comment: Also, plan on getting very used to using the terminal. It's your best path to doing programming with all sorts of languages, and essential for web-development.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the help! "rehash subl" just tells me that the command is not found. "pico ~/.bash_profile" opens up up this screen that has option in the bottom and I'm not sure if that's supposed to happen? I just typed "pico .bash_profile" from that home directory (I assumed that's what you meant". I added the output from env $PATH for you to see. Thanks again, I really appreciate this.

Comment: Does your PATH really end with ": No such file or directory"? Get that out of there if so, as that's not a path entry. `pico` is a text editor. That's why you were going to open ~/.bash_profile, right? You needed to add `~/bin:` to your PATH variable, right? A simple search for "pico" would turn up information on its use. See http://web.archive.org/web/20080428080631/http://www.ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece250/Online/Unix/pico You can also search for "nano" which is what the "pico" command actually uses.

Comment: @user2469211, Stack Overflow notified me that you attempted to modify the answer to add your path to it. That's considered really bad form. Instead, you should add any information to your original question at the bottom of your question, so everyone knows where to find the information you added.